# JavaScript CallBack throwing TypeError in Xamarin.Android

Tags: javascript, callback, xamarin.android, android-webview, custom-renderer

I am adding a webview with javascript enabled and also with the javascript interface in my Xamarin.android project. But the moment I try to call the native C# method from javascript I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showMessage' of undefined.`

**Code to enable javascript interface**

```
Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
Control.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
Control.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "TextSelection") ;
```

**JavaScript interface code**

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public void showMessage(string message)
{
Console.WriteLine("Javascript_callback--> message " + message);
}
```

**Code to call the C# method from javascript**

```
var text = window.getSelection().toString();
TextSelection.showMessage(text);
```

I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Note: I tried this code instead, but the error still occurred.

```
[JavascriptInterface]
[Export("showMessage")]
public void showMessage(string message)
{
Console.WriteLine("Javascript_callback--> message " + message);
}
```

Comment: I test your code in my demo, I could run it normally, please close VS, open your project folder, delete all of the `bin` and `obj` folders, then re-build your project, If this issue is still existed, If it is still existed, please upload a demo to github